# Readjusting brakes after every wheel removal?

Tags: brakes

Today I had a puncture and had to remove the back wheel of my bike (the wheel has a quick release skewer).

After re-inserting the wheel, the rim is grinding at one side of the brake (the brake is a "Linear-pull brake" or "direct-pull brake", commonly referred to by "V-brake").

After quite some manual fine tuning of the quick release skewer, I was able to remove the grinding of the brake at the rim.

My question:

1. Is manual fine tuning of the settlement of the quick release skewer the best way to avoid rim grinding?
2. Or is it better to adjust the v-brakes brake shoes after reassembling the wheel?

Solution 2 seems to be more time consuming for me, but maybe it has some advantages, too?

---

EDITs: The rim is more or less true.

Comment: Just braking once should re-center the pads... Did you tried that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is manual fine tuning of the settlement of the quick release skewer the best way to avoid rim grinding?

The quick release skewer is notorious for not always aligning the wheel straight. Especially for disc brakes that have very minimal pad gap, it may not be possible to get the quick release in exactly the same position repeatedly. This is one of the reasons disc brake bikes have switched to thru axles that assure repeated exact alignment of the wheel. (Another reason being that front disc brakes have the quick release self-loosen and then during braking the loose quick release can cause wheel ejection because the disc brake pushes the left end of front axle away from the dropout.)

For those reasons I don't use disc brake quick release bikes. For rim brake quick release bikes, what I do is the following:

- Put large fraction of my weight on top of the top tube, or if attaching the rear wheel and the bike has rear rack, on top of the rear rack (you have to be careful here as rear racks are usually rated for 25 kg max, although on bumpy rides 25 kg load can be momentarily be as high as 50 kg or even more) -- to be precise, I'm sitting on the top tube, left leg on the left side of the bike, right leg on the right side of the bike
- Ensure I'm pushing down on the bike as symmetrically as I can
- Close the quick release while still sitting on the top tube (I'm actually using axles with Allen-like five-sided security key so I can't just close it, I have to rotate it to tighten it)

I find that with these procedures, I'm able to repeatedly align the wheel well enough that the brake centering doesn't require any adjustment.

> 2. Or is it better to adjust the v-brakes brake shoes after reassembling the wheel?

No. Put enough of your weight on the bike symmetrically while closing the quick release and it'll be aligned.

Even if you aren't as successful in the symmetrical load trick as I am, you shouldn't touch the V brake shoes at all, since quality V brakes have a centering screw on both brake arms.

> Solution 2 seems to be more time consuming for me, but maybe it has some advantages, too?

It is very time consuming to adjust the shoe position. However, even if you can't make my trick work, the centering screw shouldn't take more than half a minute, including the time to fetch and return the Allen key.